# language cross-cutting concern memory allocator that tracks usage and a logger

Tags: c, software

I have two cross cutting concerns in my design of my software.  The memory allocator tracks memory usage in its struct(class) member variables.  I also have a logger.  Right now I am passing the logger and the allocator into the constructor of my objects.  I can maintain a reference to them but then I would have to do that in every struct(class) I create.  It would be nice if they were global but I am not sure how to do that in C. Can I construct a global memory allocator that will correctly keep track of bytes used without passing it in to my functions calls to reference?

Comment: see [Why is “Is it possible to…” a poorly worded question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7274/31260)

Comment: C is not object-oriented.  To what are you referring when you say "objects?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey C support for objects is admittedly anemic compared to some other languages, but you can write OO code in it just fine. And C objects are defined in a most basic manner, as memory holding values of specific types. One of the more "object-oriented" constructors of C objects is `fopen()`.

Comment: @Deduplicator: Well, I'm not comfortable with calling that method a "constructor" but I could see how the struct so returned might be considered an "object." **ref:** http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Comment: That's fine, in the nitty-gritty the problem is that there are too many reasonable definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Try Aspect Oriented Programming.

Logging is a cross cutting concern. It's normal to need it in every struct/class. It's normal to not want to pass a log into every single struct/object, it's normal to not want to inject some context or service locator that knows your logger, it's normal to not want to create a global logger and it's normal to not want to hard code a static reference to your logger.  Although that last one is popular in the self4j / log4j world.

An alternative is to let your code remain completely unaware that it's even being logged.

See:  http://www.aspectc.org/